# Check which services are running on the server (python script) and restart them if they have stopped?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, mongodb

I am trying to write a python script which shows me the services which are running on my server.

The thing is that mongodb keeps going down on the server and each time it happens I have to manually write the command to start it up.

What I wanted to do was automate this job for some services if they go down.

Currently i have written this https://gist.github.com/prodicus/67609dd984309d0a82f9

I know its really basic guys. It has miles to go :)

Now how do I start the services **mongodb** and **apache** through this script ?
Any suggestions would be really helpful guys.

Comment: Why not edit the service to "respawn"? I would consider that the best method. See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm all for teaching yourself how to do this kind of thing as a learning exercise, but figured I would mention that in addition to the respawn option mentioned in the comments, there are several options for doing this already written:

- [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/)
- [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)
- [Perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=about)
- [Daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html)

There are probably others too.  Most of these have published source too, so you can look for pointers in their implementation, bugs etc. if you want to continue to write your own.

Comment: Thank @Adam C. 
Any good tutorial for Supervisor and perp ?

Comment: I've recently used supervisor for Docker containes like this: http://nerdist.com/this-madden-16-commercial-is-the-most-ridiculous-thing-youll-ever-watch/ This looks like a decent, Ubuntu specific tutorial that covers the basics: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps  It's been a long time since I used perp, so nothing to hand for that one I'm afraid